# How to format scope in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have several `$scope` with content.

**HTML** :

```
<td>{{ project.captation }}</td>
<td>{{ project.perso }}</td>
```

**Output** :

content1

```
Random text here...
```

content2

```
- Lorem ipsum- quia dolor sit ame- consectetur adipiscing elit
```

**JS (controller)** :

```
$http({
    url: "php/random.php",
    method: "GET"
}).success(function(data) {
    $scope.project = data;
});
```

I would like to replace each `-` by `<li>....</li>` only in the case where there is a `-`.
How to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
var items = $scope.project.perso.split('-');
if (items.length > 1) {
    var list = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        list += "<li>" + items[i] + "</li>";
    }
    $scope.project.perso = list;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I use this with the @Sandeep Panda's anwser !

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom filter which replaces `-` with `<li>...</li>`. See this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) to get started with filters. Then use the filter as following in your HTML template:

```
<td>{{ project.captation | filterNameHere }}</td>
<td>{{ project.perso | filterNameHere }}</td>
```